# Keyboard and Mouse don't work

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

I have a desktop that runs `Windows XP`. All of a sudden the mouse and keyboard stopped responding(they are both microsoft wireless).

The first thing I tried was to change the USB port of the transmitter but they still don't work. The next move was to change keyboard and mouse. I tried a PS2 keyboard I had spare, but it didn't seem to be working. I also used another wireless mouse in various usb ports, but again no signal!

All these mice and keyboards work perfect in other desktop/laptops.

I have to mention that keyboard is working like a charm on `BIOS`.

The last step was to use a live USB `ubuntu 12.04` stick. In loads fine and both keyboard and mouse are working perfectly.

What can I do to fix the problem and use the keyboard and mouse in windows?

Comment: So you are saying a non-wireless USB keyboard and mouse did not function on this system?

Comment: Try to reset the BIOS to factory defaults.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thank you very much for your comment! A PS2 keyboard isn't working on windows. But everything is working on `BIOS` and `ubuntu 12.04`.

Comment: Get rid of XP..

Comment: I do not understand why the question received negative votes.

Comment: @TiagoCA: Thank you for your time! How to reset the default `BIOS` settings? Is this surely, safe...? Once I did it, for another problem, and I was facing hardware issues with the audio, network and graphics card...  cannot explain the negative votes either...

Comment: @MDMoore313: Unfortunately this isn't up to me... I don't even use the PC... My girlfriend does, because she needs some statistics packages that are only for windows....

Comment: @Thanos: We are here to help you :). See this article that explains how to reset the bios: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000976.htm

Comment: Do you know that PS/2 devices must be connected at boot to work? Try to shutdown the PC, then plug in PS/2 keyboard and mouse and start Windows, then let us know if it worked.

Comment: @gronostaj: The moment you commented I just rembered it... I restarted and the PS2 mouse worked.... Then windows started, I logged in and the software for wireless keyboard/mouse instaleed automatically. And now it's working!!!

Answer (score 1):

Statistics as in SAS or SPSS? Those are available for Windows 7, XP is going to be end of life in less than a year, I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but you're barking up the wrong tree. There's little point in resetting the BIOS when it works on the live USB, *especially* if the mouse and keyboard work in the BIOS. The problem is the OS, you can try reloading the drivers like the first answer said, but since PS2 devices have the same problem you'll probably wind up spending several hours tracking the problem down, which could be spent backing up your girlfriend's data and doing a clean install of Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I turned of the system, plugged in the PS2 mouse and logged in windows.

The OS automatically installed the software for the wireless keyboard and mouse. Now everything is working like a charm!